# Align text into a div

Tags: css

My float div contain just text and i want to align it vertically at the middle

HTML:

```
<div>CC</div>
```

I try this

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    float: left; /* this element is necessary for my big other code so i have to keep it */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But it didn't work, how can i fix it ? here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHxUr/9/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:table-cell;` to accomplish this. Like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">CC</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid;
    display:table;
}
.content {
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHxUr/5/)

Comment: I forgot in my code there is a `float : left` your code didn't work with it [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHxUr/9/)

Comment: Just remove `text-align:center;` then, no need to float as the text is left-aligned by default. I just figured you wanted it to be centered vertically and horizontally. Is this what you're going for? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHxUr/12/)

Comment: i update my question ... no i have absolutely to keep my div to `float: left` because it's just a little part of my big code.

Comment: Unless you are setting a static width on the containing div there is no reason to float it. Even if you are, it works fine, see here: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHxUr/13/)

Comment: i need a solution with float div.

Comment: This solution works fine with a floated div, as seen in the Fiddle above.

Comment: i didn't see it i will take a look ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54680/discussion-between-apad1-and-youssef).

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` :)

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHxUr/3/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single word or a short line of text, you could simply use the following CSS:

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Set the `line-height` to be the same as the `height` and then apply `vertical-align: middle`, works well if you have a single line of text.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/2En98/

Answer (score 0):

You can use text-align property instead of vertical-align then use "center" as value;

Simply as follows:

```
  div {
       text-align: center;
  }
```